# Is this calculation about mean thermal photon number correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

The mean photon number $n$ whose wavenumber is $\lambda$ at thermal equilibrium at temperature $T$ is given as

$$n = \frac{\exp(-h\nu/kT)}{1 - \exp(-h\nu/kT)} = \frac{1}{\exp(h\nu/kT)-1}$$

and I calculate using $h = 6.626\times 10^{-34}$, $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda} = \frac{3\times 10^{8}}{1500\times 10^{-9}}$, $k = 1.380\times 10^{-24}$, $T = 300\,\rm K$

I got $n = 1.301\times 10^{-14}$. Is that correct?

I think this calculation is wrong, because the order of the photon number at room temperature is about $0.01$.

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: The two latter parts of your equation are not equal.  Meaning, $e^{-x}/(1-e^{-x})$ is not the same as $1/(e^{-x} - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is wrong

Notice, the value of the Boltzman constant is $\color{red}{k=1.38\times 10^{-23}\ J/K}$ then substituting the values, you should find mean photon number $$n=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}-1}=\large \frac{1}{exp\left({\frac{6.626\times 10^{-34}\times 3\times 10^{8}}{1500\times 10^{-9}\times 1.38\times 10^{-23}\times 300}}\right)-1}=\color{blue}{1.2603\times 10^{-14}}$$